# Automatically switch-off air plane mode in android

Tags: java, android

I need to turn off flight mode automatically.I used following code for this.but  it isn't working.

```
java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [su, -c, settings put global airplane_mode_on 0] Working Directory: null Environment: null
```

My code

```
public void modifyAirplanemode(boolean mode) {

    /* Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTINGS);
     intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     getActivity().startActivity(intent);*/

    String command = COMMAND_FLIGHT_MODE_1+" "+0;
    executeCommandWithoutWait(getActivity(), "-c", command);
    command = COMMAND_FLIGHT_MODE_2 + " " +false;
    executeCommandWithoutWait(getActivity(), "-c", command);

}
private void executeCommandWithoutWait(Context context, String option, String command) {
    boolean success = false;
    String su = "su";
    for (int i=0; i < 3; i++) {
        // "su" command executed successfully.
        if (success) {
            // Stop executing alternative su commands below. 
            break;
        }
        if (i == 1) {
            su = "/system/xbin/su";
        } else if (i == 2) {
            su = "/system/bin/su";
        }       
        try {
            // execute command
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{su, option, command});
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }   
    }
```

I need to work with above android 4.2

Comment: you are not using the parameter passed to `modifyAirplanemode`. Is this correct behavior?

Comment: Automatically turning off flight mode seems like a really, really bad idea.  Think about it ...